# SSRS Report to check conditions and hide table data

Tags: sql, reporting-services

This one worked in the past and its deployed but all of a sudden it is started throwing an error. In the Tablix properties I have to check these 3 conditions:

`=IIF(DATEDIFF("d", Parameters!startDate.Value, Parameters!endDate.Value) > 30 AND Parameters!startDate.Value > Today() AndAlso Parameters!endDate.Value > Today() AND Parameters!startDate.Value >= Parameters!endDate.Value, True,False)`

If I choose end date as todays date it is throwing a message but it is also displaying data. Please help me. It worked earlier, it used to show only message saying date is future date. Now it is displaying data also. I don't want the data to be displayed. TIA.

Comment: why is there an andAlso on the second line? Didn't know SSRS did natural language. ;)

Comment: In logical operations AndAlso was available.

Answer (score 0):

Is this expression in the `Hidden` property of the tablix? 
If so then the way it is written means that all the conditions must be true for it to be hidden. If I've read it correctly, if startDate was yesterday but endDate was tomorrow, the result will be `False` so the tablix would display.

If you are just trying to test if any date is in the future or the dates are more than 30 days apart then you could do something like this.

```
=IIF(
    DATEDIFF("d", Parameters!startDate.Value, Parameters!endDate.Value) > 30 
    OR Parameters!startDate.Value > Today() 
    OR Parameters!endDate.Value > Today()
    , True
    , False
    )
```

Comment: +1, @Alan Schofield, 
Yes It is in the Hidden property of tablix. If start date was yesterday and end date is today, it should throw error message and should not display the data.

=IIF(DATEDIFF("d", Parameters!startDate.Value, Parameters!endDate.Value) > 30 Or Parameters!startDate.Value > Today() AndAlso Parameters!endDate.Value > Today() Or Parameters!startDate.Value >= Parameters!endDate.Value, True,False)

with this it is throwing error message and also displaying data.